# Saving output to files

Tags: java, file, dataoutputstream

I currently am trying to put the values that are created through my object into a file. My output for the program works fine and my computations in another class's methods work. I would just like to save the the output of matrixApp into a file. I also show what my output looks like without trying to save to a file. The route that I have taken doesn't seem to be working, any suggestions?

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MatrixApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m, n, p, q;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of first matrix");
    m = input.nextInt();
    n = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of second matrix");
    p = input.nextInt();
    q = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the elements of first matrix");

    int first[][] = new int[m][n];
    for (int c = 0; c < m; c++)
        for (int d = 0; d < n; d++)
            first[c][d] = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the elements of second matrix");
    int second[][] = new int[p][q];

    for (int c = 0; c < p; c++)
        for (int d = 0; d < q; d++)
            second[c][d] = input.nextInt();



    MatrixMult matrixApp = new MatrixMult(first, second, m, n, p, q);

    //String filename = "data.txt";
    //FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    //BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
    //DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(bout);
    //for (int i=0; i < matrixApp; i++){ <--- the problem is here and 
        //dout.writeInt(matrixApp[][]);   getting the program to do all the 
    //}                                   the outputs
  }
}
```

The MatrixMult class

```
public class MatrixMult{

public MatrixMult(int first[][], int second[][], int m, int n, int p, int q) {
    doMatrixMultiply(first, second, m, n, p, q);
}

public void doMatrixMultiply(int first[][], int second[][], int m, int n, int p, int q) {

    if (n != p)
        System.out
                .println("Matrices with entered orders can't be multiplied with each other.");
    else {
        int multiply[][] = new int[m][q];
        int addition[][] = new int[m][q];
        int transpose[][] = new int[m][q];
        int transpose2[][] = new int[m][q];

        int mult = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int tran = 0;


        for (int c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < q; d++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < p; k++) {
                    mult = mult + first[c][k] * second[k][d];
                }

                multiply[c][d] = mult;
                mult = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Product of entered matrices:-");

        for (int c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < q; d++)
                System.out.print(multiply[c][d] + "\t");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        for (int c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < q; d++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < p; k++) {
                    sum = first[c][d] + second[c][d];
                }

                addition[c][d] = sum;
                sum = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sum of entered matrices:-");

        for (int c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < q; d++)
                System.out.print(addition[c][d] + "\t");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        int c;
        int d;
        for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
                transpose[d][c] = first[c][d];
        }
        for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
                transpose2[d][c] = second[c][d];
        }

        System.out.println("Transpose of first entered matrix:-");

        for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            for (d = 0; d < m; d++)
                System.out.print(transpose[c][d] + "\t");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Transpose of second entered matrix:-");

        for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            for (d = 0; d < m; d++)
                System.out.print(transpose2[c][d] + "\t");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
  }
}
```

The output of matrixApp is

Product of entered matrices:-

1   -2  -4
-1  7   -18

7   1   5
Sum of entered matrices:-

4   0   -3
4   4   -5
2   -1  7
Transpose of first entered matrix:-

2   1   1
-1  0   1
0   -3  2
Transpose of second entered matrix:-

2   3   1
1   4   -2
-3  -2  5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not closing your streams - which are *explicitly* buffered. So everything is in memory, and you never gets flushed to disk. Use a try-with-resources statement to close everything appropriately, even if an exception is thrown.:

```
try (FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);
     BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
     DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(bout)) {
    // Note: Body here is as per original question. It won't compile, but
    // we don't know what was expected.
    for (int i=0; i < matrixApp; i++){
        dout.writeInt(matrixApp[][]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `i < matrixApp` works when matrixApp is `MatrixMult` ? Also, how does `writeInt(matrixApp[][])` compile ?

Comment: try still produces the same result, but I will add it for thrown exceptions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: That was just copied from the OP's code. Will add a note.

Comment: @Ryhart: The code you've provided won't actually compile at the moment, which makes it harder to help you.

Comment: @Ryhart: Have you debugged through the real code (as opposed to the non-compiling code)? Do you ever get to `writeInt`?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Everything works except when I add the the statements to create the file. I have just been toying around with the output of the matrixApp and now would like to save it to a file. I just can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @Ryhart: The code you've given *doesn't* work - it wouldn't even compile, as I've said before. That means that you're probably not running the code you've posted. Now, as I asked before, when you debugged through the code, did you get as far as the `writeInt` calls? If so, I would be *very* surprised if the file was really empty afterwards. Are you sure you're looking at the right file?

Comment: @JonSkeet: The start of the writeInt calls is where the problem starts. Nothing is being saved into the file created.

Comment: @Ryhart: What do you mean by "where the problem starts"? For the third time, have you validated with a debugger that you *get* that far? If you put a `System.out.println("I'm writing to the file");` *just* after the `dout.writeInt()` call (still in the loop) do you see that? Do you let the program run to completion? I note you've now commented out the code which calls `writeInt` - why? Why not just present the code that *does* compile, but which calls `writeInt`? It's *really* frustrating trying to help you but not getting all the information we need.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to save a `MatrixMult` object named `matrixApp`.

Why not serialize it ?

Implement `java.io.Serializable` in `MatrixMult` then call `dout.writeObject(matrixApp)`.

---

**Edit**

As per your comment, here a [simple example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) on how to serialize/de-serialize.

---

If you dont want to use serialization,

> I would just like to save the the output of matrixApp into a file.

Assuming *"the the output"* is the `first` and `second` matrix,

```
for (int i=0; i < first.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; k < first[i].length; j++)
        dout.writeInt(first[i][j]);

for (int i=0; i < second.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; k < second[i].length; j++)
        dout.writeInt(second[i][j]);
```

Put that in a `try` with ressource as @JonSkeet explained.

Comment: sounds interesting, but I haven't learned about serialization yet. Trying to figure out how to impliment

Comment: @Ryhart add `implements Serializable` in the declaration of your `MatrixMult` object. I've added a link with a short example.

Comment: Java's default serialization is a pain in the neck. There are lots of gotchas, particularly in versioning. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @JonSkeet What is wrong with serializing a custom object where you define the serialization behaviour yourself ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: The default Java serialization (as you've described it - just implementing `Serializable` and getting the default behaviour) means that even simple changes which shouldn't really affect anything (e.g. adding a method but no state) break compatibility unless you're careful. The result is *only* usable in Java, hard to decode by hand, etc. Even with care, it's very hard to make the sort of forward/backward-compatible changes that something like Protocol Buffers allows. I've used Java serialization in a few different cases, and it's always caused pain.

Comment: @JonSkeet Isn't it why we use `serialVersionUID` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: your edit helps, but is there no way to go through entire output of the matrixApp to save those results. I edited my original post with the outcome I am trying to save.

Comment: @Ryhart It would help seeing how is built your `MatrixMult` class as we have no idea what happen when constructing it. Yes, there is certainly a way but I need more info.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: I have included the MatrixMult class

Comment: @Ryhart You could simply do the writing treatment in the `MatrixMult` class, change the println for `dout.write`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: Yes, that's why `serialVersionUID` is present - but it's a pain to do it all properly. (A really significant pain, in my experience.)